# Prove that the equation $3x-\sin(2x)=0$ has only one solution

Tags: calculus

I`m trying to prove that this equation has only one solution$$3x-\sin(2x)=0$$
I need some advice how to do that, Thanks!

EDIT
 [image: graph]

Comment: Have you drawn a diagram yet?

Comment: Do you know what the graph of $y=\sin2x$ looks like? and the graph of $y=3x$?

Comment: yes, but how I prove it by writing it, to show the graph is good but its not enough

Comment: Drawing the graph is not meant to be the solution --- it is meant to steer you in the right direction to give the solution. Tell us what you see in the graph.

Comment: its strictly increasing as I see

Comment: Yes --- can you prove that? Alternatively, I suggested drawing *two* graphs.

Comment: if I drawing two graphs I see that its only cross at x axis

Comment: The graph (or two graphs) can highlight features of the equation which may not be obvious from reading the formulae - your one graph is clearly strictly increasing. Now you know what you are looking to prove, you can look for an appropriate method.

Comment: yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By intermediate value theorem it clearly has at least one solution (or just check by plugging in $x=0$). Now the derivative of $3x-\sin(2x)$ is $3-2\cos(2x)>0$, hence the function is strictly increasing, hence it can cross the x-axis only once, ergo only one solution.

Comment: So I need to show that the function is strictly increasing and its ensure me that it has only one solution?, OK got it!

Comment: Well, Ofir, think about it --- if a function is strictly increasing, can it be zero more than once?

Answer (score 0):

Given the range of $\sin 2x$, it's easy to find an interval in which all the solutions must lie. In this interval, the function has a certain property which immediately tells you there can be at most one solution. By giving an explicit solution, you'll prove that there's at least one solution.